# 404 Not Found for Greek Language installation

Tags: language-support

I want to install Greek language support for my Ubuntu 12.10. I go through system settings -> Language Support, check the Greek but when the system tries to download the files I get a:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-el_18.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found
```

I tried to hit the URL from my browser and I still get a 404. My internet connection works fine.
I'm pretty new at Ubuntu so can you please help me with that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The file you're looking for is simply not there. From what I can see from http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/ there's a newer version there - which probably means that the repository lists on your systems are outdated.

You will want to update your repository lists - run the command `apt-get update` from a command line, then try installing language support again - this should let you download the latest version of the files, and everything should work